# Giving alias name to datatype of Property during serialization

Tags: c#

I have a class which I need to serialize using XMLserializer in C#

```
[DataContract]
Public class X
{
[Datamember]
Public List<string> CodeList {get;set;}
}
```

But as the Data type of CodeList is string, I am getting below xml

```
<CodeList>
<string>asd</string>
<string>cvb</string>
</CodeList>
```

But I want to show the xml in the format wherein string is shown as code i.e I want to give string an alias name of code.

```
<CodeList>
<Code>asd</Code>
<Code>cvb</Code>
</CodeList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention using the `XMLSerializer` but you are using attributes for the `DataContractSerializer`. If you stick to using the `XMLSerializer` it is dead simple.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X x = new X();
        x.CodeList = new List<string>() {"test", "test1"};
        var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (X));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
        xml.Serialize(writer,x);
        writer.Close();
    }
}

public class X
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Code")]
    public List<string> CodeList { get; set; } 
}
```

You notice that I don't need any attributes other than the `[XmlArrayItem]`. That is because the `XmlSerializer` will go ahead and serialize all public properties. If that is a problem, you can use the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute]`, which will ignore a property while serializing.

This is the output I got from my code above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<X xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CodeList>
    <Code>test</Code>
    <Code>test1</Code>
  </CodeList>
</X>
```

Comment: @Sunil I'm glad it is working. Please mark my answer as accepted if you feel that it solved your problem